# Fixing Cumulative Layout Shift in Div

Tags: html, core-web-vitals, cumulative-layout-shift

I'm trying to optimize my website to prevent [Cumulative Layout Shifts](https://web.dev/cls/) and have mostly fixed everything. However, Chrome Developer Tools complains that the following code block suffers from CLS:

```
<div class="colorlib-services colorlib-bg-white">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center animate-box">
                <div class="services">
                    <div class="desc">
                        <h3>
                            <a href="Home/MySite" target="_blank">
                                <img src="~/images/Logo.svg" width="208" height="78" asp-append-version="true" />
                            </a>
                        </h3>
                        <p>Text</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center animate-box">
                <div class="services">
                    <div class="desc">
                        <h3>
                            <a href="Home/About" target="_blank">
                                <img src="~/images/Logo2.svg" width="208" height="78" asp-append-version="true" />
                            </a>
                        </h3>
                        <p>More text</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center animate-box">
                <div class="services">
                    <div class="desc">
                        <h3 style="margin-top:25px;">Other Services</h3>
                        <p style="margin-top:40px;">Other</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there another in this code which may be causing a layout shift? My image resolutions are set and I don't see anything that might be causing a pop-in effect.

Comment: Without seeing this code in context, it will be very hard to tell you why you are getting CLS issues. It could be animation, since your page loads and then elements animate in which appear to Chrome as CLS.

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code or paste this in console to get the details of Layout Shift events. In each entry you will be able to find `LayoutShiftAttribution.node` property which points to the DOM element causing the layout shift.

```
let clsValue = 0;
let clsEntries = [];

let sessionValue = 0;
let sessionEntries = [];

new PerformanceObserver((entryList) => {
  for (const entry of entryList.getEntries()) {
    // Only count layout shifts without recent user input.
    if (!entry.hadRecentInput) {
      const firstSessionEntry = sessionEntries[0];
      const lastSessionEntry = sessionEntries[sessionEntries.length - 1];

      // If the entry occurred less than 1 second after the previous entry and
      // less than 5 seconds after the first entry in the session, include the
      // entry in the current session. Otherwise, start a new session.
      if (sessionValue &&
          entry.startTime - lastSessionEntry.startTime < 1000 &&
          entry.startTime - firstSessionEntry.startTime < 5000) {
        sessionValue += entry.value;
        sessionEntries.push(entry);
      } else {
        sessionValue = entry.value;
        sessionEntries = [entry];
      }

      // If the current session value is larger than the current CLS value,
      // update CLS and the entries contributing to it.
      if (sessionValue > clsValue) {
        clsValue = sessionValue;
        clsEntries = sessionEntries;

        // Log the updated value (and its entries) to the console.
        console.log('CLS:', clsValue, clsEntries)
      }
    }
  }
}).observe({type: 'layout-shift', buffered: true});
```